# Resizing a spark group by setting width and height

Tags: apache-flex

I have been given the seemingly simply task of resizing a Group container by setting width and height explicitly in response to user interaction. However, changing these values have no effect on the size of the container at all. Changing scaleX and/or scaleY will change the size of the container just fine, but this is not the behavior I am after.

I have tried overriding updateDisplayList() to set a specific width and height, but this has not yielded the desired results.

If anyone has a link to a good tutorial or can contribute in any other way to a solution, then I would greatly appreciate it. Google does not seem to be my friend on this one.

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" ;
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    width="400" height="300"
    click="resize()">
    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[ 
            private function resize():void 
            { 
                width = 500; 
                height = 300; 
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample code where the issue can be replicated?

Comment: user700284. Something like this would do it:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" click="resize()">
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
private function resize():void
{
width = 500;
height = 300;
}
]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Group>`

(Sorry for comment spam. My fingers are not good friends with my keyboard today)

Comment: please next time edit your question to share code, don't paste long code lines inside comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your approach works just fine, but you need to have some content inside that group, or use a `BorderContainer` instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    click="doResize();">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function doResize():void
            {
                this.width = 300;
                this.height = 200;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Group>
```

To stick to your problem, I've put a `TextArea` into this Group instance from the main application, and it gets resized.

Comment: I do have content in my group. I just did not include it in the example code. I really can't understand why this is not working for me. Could it be because my group is nested inside another group that is scaled?

Comment: What kind of content do you have in your `Group`? Does it have a visual layout, so you could tell if it is resized?

Comment: I have another group and a couple of elements that extend SpriteVisualElement.

Comment: Any of them docked to the right/bottom of your resizing `Group` of filling the width/height of it, so the resizing to be visible?

Comment: Hmm. That could potentially explain it. Let me check

Comment: That was the reason. So simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your group is visually empty and `click` handler is never called. Try using a `BorderContainer` with `backgroundColor`.

Comment: click is called. I have place a trace inside it. I have also just tried using a BorderContainer and still the same result. Or should I say, the same missing result.